# Using non-blocking socket. errno is always EAGAIN after calling recvfrom

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp

I'm porting my networking code from Windows to Linux, but not without problems.
For some reason, recvfrom wont work properly when I'm setting the socket to be non-blocking. You see, errno is always EAGAIN after I call recvfrom and it doesn't matter how many packets I receive, it's always EAGAIN. The code is running fine if I comment out the code that's setting the socket to be no-blocking. Well then it's working, but it's blocking...

Here's the code I'm using to set the socket to non-blocking:

```
int nonBlocking = 1;
if ( fcntl( handle, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK, nonBlocking ) == -1 )
{
    std::cout << "failed to set non-blocking socket" << std::endl;
    return false;
}
```

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?
(It's working fine in my Windows build using:

```
DWORD nonBlocking = 1;
ioctlsocket( handle, FIONBIO, &nonBlocking );
```

Comment: I'm calling recvfrom every single loop. That's why I need it to be nonblocking. But right now it's not blocking my application from doing other things, but it is ignoring/blocking my incoming packets?

Comment: Are you saying you read and process packets perfectly fine when you do not set the socket to non-blocking ? Anyway, getting EAGAIN when there is no packets is normal. How do you know it should not return EAGAIN at any given time ?

Comment: I'm asking you, will it? Is it wrong to discard the packet if errno == to EAGAIN?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at, EAGAIN means that there was no packet right now. That's what setting the socket to non-blocking does, it'll make recv/read/recvfrom/etc. return EAGAIN if there's no data right now instead of blocking until something arrives.

Answer (score 3):

First, before check the `errno` value, you should check the return value of `recvfrom()`.

If it returns `-1` then `errno` value will make sense.

From `recvfrom` manpage:

> If  no messages are available at the socket, the receive calls wait
>   for
>          a message to arrive, unless the socket is nonblocking  (see  fcntl(2)),
>          in  which case the value -1 is returned and the external variable errno
>          set to EAGAIN.

In a nutshell:

at the moment you call `recvfrom`, there's nothing to read